# Round Select OPTIONS with css (PHP process-able)?

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to achieve this select options with rounded shape and the options values dead  center. Here is a snapshot:

[image: One with text and one with icon]

Here is my code so far:

```
<select size="4">
    <option value="s">S</option>
    <option value="l">L</option>
    <option value="xl">XL</option>
    <option value="xxl">XXL</option>
</select>

select {
    display:table-row;
}
option {
   display:table-cell;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Resulting this:

[image: My result so far]

Is it actually achievable? I can do this with span and div along with jQuery but I need to submit the form straight to PHP without JS.

Thank you

Comment: nothing to do with php

Comment: With JS is okay too. You are right. Nothing to do with php. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why not. Using the class [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) we can do this...
Example:

```
<?php
$dom = new DOMDocument();
//uncomment any one of these
//$dom->loadHTML("index.html");//for html file
//$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://localhost/index.php'));//for php file

//to get element
$div = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');

//to get element array and get its attributes
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    foreach ($div->attributes as $attr) {
        $name = $attr->nodeName;
        $value = $attr->nodeValue;
        echo "Attribute '$name' :: '$value'<br />";
    }
}

//to get specific element without array
$div = $dom->getElementById('divID');
```

This was only an example, you can do much more things with this just read domdocument class reference given in top of my answer to check what we can do more.

Another option is by making a form and access it with [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal variable, but maybe this needs a button to submit. Of cource this method is more recommended than domdocument class. So I shared two options it depends on you that which one you choose